# BST Level-Order Traversal

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I have some code about BST, and i want to print out the input, with use the BST Level-Order Traversal, node-left-right. Here is code:

```
import sys

class Node:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.right=self.left=None
        self.data = data
class Solution:
    def insert(self,root,data):
        if root==None:
            return Node(data)
        else:
            if data<=root.data:
                cur=self.insert(root.left,data)
                root.left=cur
            else:
                cur=self.insert(root.right,data)
                root.right=cur
        return root


    def levelOrder(self,root):
        #Write your code here
        nodes_to_search = list()
        nodes_traversed = ''
        nodes_to_search.append(root)
        while len(nodes_to_search) > 0:
            nodes = nodes_to_search.pop(0)
            if nodes.left:
                nodes_to_search.append(nodes.left)
            if nodes.right:
                nodes_to_search.append(nodes.right)
            nodes_traversed += str(nodes.data) + ' '
        print(nodes_traversed)


T=int(input())
myTree=Solution()
root=None
for i in range(T):
    data=int(input())
    root=myTree.insert(root,data)
myTree.levelOrder(root)


6
3
5
4
7
2
1 # it prints out 3 5 2 1 4 7
```

The output is like i expected,node-left-right. But i don't understand how the `levelOrder()` function works to print like this ?

Answer (score 0):

Simple List operations, to keep the order

1. Each time we get the first element from the nodes_search_list

```
nodes = nodes_to_search.pop(0)
```

2. Push the Left child before the right child (So we always get left before right)

```
            if nodes.left:
                nodes_to_search.append(nodes.left)
            if nodes.right:
                nodes_to_search.append(nodes.right)
```

Comment: but why we don't do: if root.left: nodes_to_search.append(root.left) if root.right: nodes_to_search.append(root.right) ?

Comment: We are doing that.

Answer (score 0):

The output you are getting is not correct. If you make a BST using the inputs (3, 5, 4, 7, 2, 1), you'll get this output -- 3 2 5 1 4 7 in Level-Order Traversal [Since all lower value will left side of root element, and all the higher value will be right side of root node]. The scenario is first print root element and then go each level and print all the element in this level.

I will suggest you to do follow any of the procedure, I am given:

1. [BFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) Procedure:

   ```
    function BFSearch(Tree root){
     Queue queue.enqueue(root);
     while(queue isnot Empty){
         Root tempRoot = queue.dequeue();
         print -> tempRoot.element; // visting node

         /*break-down each level left to right*/
         if(tempRoot.left isnot Empty){
               queue.enqueue(tempRoot.left);
         }
         if(tempRoot.right isnot Empty){
              queue.enqueue(tempRoot.right);
         }
     }  
   }
   ```
2. You can use the following recursive approach too--

   ```
    function driver(){
   // visiting the root first;
     print -> root.node;

     levelOrderPrinting(root);
    } 
    function levelOrderPrinting(Tree root){
     if(root is null) 
      return;

     if(root.left isnot Empty)
      print -> root.left.node;

     if(root.right isnot Empty)
      print -> root.right.node;

     // break down each level left to right

      levelOrderPrinting(root.left);
      levelOrderPrinting(root.right);
   }
   ```